# Cisco ASA 5520 - differential routing policies based on userid

Tags: vpn, cisco, routing

excuse me if my terminology is not correct.

We are using WebVPN to VPN into an Cisco ASA 5520. We want to have different rules that allow the user that VPNs into the network to access certain things based on their RSA SecurID authentication userid. Is this possible? If so, are there some good examples of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you would put certain users into groups and then allow those groups access to certain things.  Sorry can't be more specific but haven't actually done it yet.  I'm reading anything on asa's at the moment as we are getting them in 2 months in our datacenter for edge firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

The ASA does support the functionality using the Identity based ACLs. In this case the ACLs are based on the mapped attributes such as the user ID as you described.